# Wordpress inline JS - cant get working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a simple play button for youtube video on a WordPress page.

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />

<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
    jQuery("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  ev.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```

Original code pen I found: [here](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC)

It works fine on Codepen and js fiddle but has no effect on the WP page.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you get an error in your console log? Maybe it tells you more about the problem

Comment: Check your console for errors. The first thing that comes to mind is that you are not enqueuing the jQuery library properly. If this is the case, you will see an error in the console along the lines of "unknown property:jQuery"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript
Under the **JavaScript in Posts** section:

> To include Javascript **inside** a post, you need to combine the call to
>   the script file with the call to the JavaScript itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/updatepage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>
```

I needed to put the script into a .js file and call for that file as well as the script itself.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Almost guaranteed you are not loading jQuery in this project, and your code that you are adding relies on jQuery.

In your functions.php file (in your theme folder), add the below code (be sure it is *between* php open / close tags, not before / after them.  php open tag look like `<?php` and closing tag `?>`):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_jquery');

function enqueue_my_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

**You may find other resources** that show you how to add jQuery directly to the header.php file - **do not do that.** it can (and will) cause a variety of problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {

        //jQuery should almost definitely be accessible in this scope

        var $ = jQuery;

        $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
            $('#video')[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
            ev.preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
```

This is what I would consider a hacky way of adding javascript to Wordpress.

I would recommend always having your scripts in separate files and utilizing Wordpress's PHP function `wp_enqueue_script` in order to ensure script dependency order.

Comment: Side note: if your page is `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML5, which it should be), then you can leave out `type="text/javascript"`, as that is the default value for the type attribute of script elements in HTML5.